# How to fix firebase storage rules failing client side request

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-storage

I have firebase storage rules as such:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /users/{uid}/{fileName} {
        allow read;
      allow create, update: if request.auth.uid == uid && request.resource.size <= 100 * 1024;
      allow delete: if request.auth.uid == uid;
    }
  }
}
```

And from my client side, I have flutter page that adds picture to "users/${uid}/profile_pic.png" with valid size. The write request is still not allowed, giving the following error:

```
E/flutter (31434): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_storage/unauthorized] User is not authorized to perform the desired action.
```

This code uploads the image

```
await storage.ref("users/${auth.currentUser!.uid}/profile_pic.png").putData(picBytes!);
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /users/{uid}/{fileName} {
        allow read;
      allow create, update: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == uid && request.resource.size <= 100 * 1024;
      allow delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == uid;
    }
  }
}
```

As per https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-and-auth

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i dont understand how using token would allow me to make the rules work? Because i cant check for whether the users uid is equal to the uid of the folder using `auth.token`. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Forgot about Token. I've edited my answer. You can use that rules. Hope it will help you.